# Solving $\frac{dP}{dt} = k(M-P)P$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving for $P(t)$.

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = k(M-P)P$$

This is a question related to population. I'm not the best at math and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the reciprocal of both sides and integrate with respect to P. Use partial fractions to write the RHS in terms of something which is easier to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, rearrange the given ODE in the following way

\begin{align*}
P^{\prime} = k(M-P)P \Longleftrightarrow \frac{P^{\prime}}{(M-P)P} = k 
\end{align*}

Then you have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(M-P)P} = \frac{1}{M}\times\frac{M - P + P}{(M-P)P} = \frac{1}{M}\times\left(\frac{1}{P} + \frac{1}{M-P}\right)
\end{align*}

Consequently, we obtain the desired solution
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{M}\int\left(\frac{P^{\prime}}{P} + \frac{P^{\prime}}{M-P}\right)\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{M}\left(\ln|P| - \ln|P-M|\right) = kt + c = \int k\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The ODE is a Bernoulli ODE:
$$\frac{dP}{dt}-kMP=KP^2=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{P^2}\frac{dP}{dt}-\frac{kM}{P}=k.$$
Let $1/P=y$, then the ODE is 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+kMy=-k.$$ This is liear ODE whose integrating factor is $e^{kMt}.$
Hence its solution is $$y=-e^{-kMt} \int k e^{kMt} dt + C e^{-kMt} \Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{M}+ C e^{kMt} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{P}=-\frac{1}{M}+Ce^{-kMt}.$$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $M=1$ and $k=1$ (normalize $P$ and $t$). The equation is separable. We assume $0\le P\le 1$.

$$\int_{P_0}^P\frac{dP}{(1-P)P}=\left.\log\frac P{1-P}\right|_{P_0}^P=t$$

and from this

$$P=\frac{P_0e^t}{P_0(e^t-1)+1}=1-\frac{1-P_0}{P_0(e^t-1)+1}.$$

Note that $P=0$ and $P=1$ are also solutions.

A few of them:

[image]